# Android Toggle Switch to make it on or off by data

Tags: android

If the data I have pulled from the Firebase database is true, I want toggle switch to be on, and false to be off. How do I set the status of being on or off when I open the app? Product in the following `code.getstates() == enabled`, I wanted to enable if true, but it's not working right now.

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
     DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final   DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("states");
    holder.viewStatus.setChecked(product.getStates());

            if(product.getStates() == true) {
        holder.viewStatus.isChecked();

    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For toggle you need to use

```
holder.viewStatus.setChecked(true);
```

or

```
holder.viewStatus.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) { Product product = productList.get(position);

        holder.viewStatus.setChecked(product.getStates());

        if(product.getStates() == true) {
            holder.viewStatus.setChecked(true);

        }
        if (product.getStates() == false) {
            holder.viewStatus.setChecked(false);
} // He's running the code here, but it's not working.